# Should implementation of System.IFormattable.Format(...) throw an exception?

Tags: c#, formatting

I am creating an API with classes that implement `System.IFormattable` interface. To help figure out implementation details, I ran some tests on existing `IFormattable` structs in mscorlib. I was surprised by the result of executing the following code:

```
string s1 = int.MaxValue.ToString("ABC", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
string s2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("ABC", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Instead of throwing an exception for unrecognized format string, both method calls simply returned the string `"ABC"`.

When I try:

```
string s3 = int.MinValue.ToString("ABC", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

it returns `"-ABC"`  (?!?!)

What is the reason for this unexpected behavior and is it a pattern that should be followed for all `IFormattable` classes?

Comment: For some types the format string is a mix of literal text and placeholders, which is a useful feature in principle. But I'm not a fan of the "every unknown character is a literal" rule, since it prevents adding new placeholders in the future.

Comment: Apparently, characters which are no predefined format specifier are copied as literal characters into the output of `ToString`. And if there is no format specifier nor a placeholder like {0}, only the literal characters will appear, with no number. Not sure, however, why the minus sign of a negative number appears always in the output, independently of the remaining format string. Also not sure why a single literal like `.ToString("A")` leads to an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allowed to throw from your implementation if the format string is invalid; see the example in the `IFormattable` example code.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3

Note at the end of the switch statement, how it throws in the default case.

Or alternatively, try with just a single character. `(5).ToString("A")` throws.

Note the other requirements of `IFormattable` though:

- You must support the format string `"G"`, which means some kind of general representation.
- You must support a null or empty format string, and treat it the same as `"G"`.
- You must support a null `IFormatProvider`, and use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` in that case.